¿Porque no ponen los votos acumulados de cerrar en la lista de preguntas?
Creo que si pusieran los votos acumulados de Cerrar cuando estamos revisando la lista de preguntas conseguiriamos cerrarlas antes y no perderiamos todos tanto el tiempo leyendo preguntas que nos pueden parecer interesantes a simple vista pero cuando entramos a verlas son un desastre en su exposición.
Es decir, que además de mostrar "0 votos", "0 respuestas", "x vistas", pusieran "x cerrar" para los que tenemos esa potestad solamente (no hace falta rallar a los que no la tienen).
Es una opinión y una sugerencia para quien lo pueda gestionar. No quiero entrar a polemizar sobre ello, pero creo que ayudaría a identificar mucho antes las preguntas "malas" y por tanto a hacerlas desaparecer lo antes posible y que no se listen tantas veces.

Supondría que es para no influir en tu decisión, para que estudies cada caso con la necesaria atención. Si aparecen los votos de cierra, es demasiada la tentación de simplemente votar con la mayoría.

Para tu info, los diamantados si vemos esa info, no en la lista pero si en cada pregunta... igual, eso implicaria un cambio a nivel de red... eso siempre hay que tenerlo en cuenta...

@gbianchi No se si te refieres al pie de la pregunta, donde yo también veo los votos de cerrar que hay acumulados, al lado de los otros enlaces para editar, compartir, seguir, reportar.  No se, yo creo que deberian aparecer en la lista para ayudar a limpiar también las colas de cierre, pues actualmente me da una pereza enorme meterme allí.

@CandidMoe En parte tienes razón, pues cuando lo veo en los pies de la pregunta, tengo esa tentación también.  Pero no estoy diciendo que votemos sin leernos la pregunta desde la lista de preguntas, sino que de ese modo podamos entrar y ver si la pregunta vale la pena o no.  No siempre estoy de acuerdo en cerrar segun que preguntas, pero de este modo, las que son evidentes, se procesan rápido. A menos que seas de gatillo fácil y votes para cerrar como tu dices, para seguir a la mayoria sin leerte nada, cosa que va con el caracter de cada uno y no necesariamente por aparecer o no en la lista.

@gbianchi Y sí, entiendo que seria un cambio a nivel de red, pero no estaria de más modernizarse y hacer cambios de tanto en tanto si son para mejor, pues facilitarian la limpieza de las colas de revisión. Y a pesar de la "tentación" de votar con la mayoria, no creo que eso influyera demasiado en dar el toque al que pregunta para que se de cuenta que su pregunta no ha cuajado lo antes posible para que pueda enmendarla, en lugar de tenerlo durante dias a la espera de una respuesta que seguramente nunca le llegará, o que no vuelva porque nadie le contesta y se crea que esto esta muerto.

ok compresible... te invito a ir a pelear esto en meta.. porque desde aca, no se puede hacer mucho...

@gbianchi Bueno, es una opción, la verdad es que desconozco como funciona internamente todo el tinglado de SO, pero creía que soltándolo aquí y si os convencia a vosotros primero, luego lo escalariais al meta en inglés, o a quien tocara.  La verdad es que me ha sorprendido tu respuesta.  Yo esperaba más o bien un "no, no puede ser" o bien un "pues deja que lo consultemos con los de arriba por si se avienen a tenerlo en cuenta y te comentamos su respuesta", pero no un "aqui no pintamos nada, no pierdas tu tiempo en este meta" tal como me parece sobreentender en tu respuesta.

Lo que te están tratando de decir es que, como estos serían cambios a nivel de red (no solo de SOes), debés proponerlo directamente en el Meta general (no esperes a que otros lo propongan por vos, sino vos hacelo por tu cuenta). Allí sí te responderían qué tan factible sería o no.

como bien dice Pada, los cambios no funcionan asi.. los cambios a nivel de red (como este, que implica un cambio de formato en las paginas) no se hace a nivel de sitio, si no a nivel de red.. y no es algo que "yo" (por decirlo de alguna forma) charle con alguien de "arriba"... es algo que la comunidad acuerda, decide que se haga, y algun dia, la empresa te da pelota y lo hace... si es que quiere... y no tiene porque venir de un diamantado.. puede venir de cualquiera... los cambios en los sitios salen de cualquiera que lo propone...

Bueno, me habeis convencido, elaboraré una pregunta sobre esto en el meta ingles cuando pueda. Gracias!  Ya os contaré lo que me hayan dicho, que no será agradable, me lo veo venir, así que me la intentaré preparar un poco mejor, je, para que la humillación no me lleve a una depresión profunda :-)
